# Can't connect to wifi on Aquaris M10

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, bq

today arrived my Aquaris M10. :-) Unfortunately I can't connect to my access point. I've managed to setup a temporary access point and updated to OTA-12, but I'm still not able to connect to my standard access point. I don't have any problems with other devices (Motorola Motoe 2, Thinkpad, BQ E4.5, ...).

After selecting the AP I've entered the password and pressed 'ok'. After a short while the password prompt showed up again. No error message. What can I do to locate the error?

Thanks for Your answers in advance. :-)

Peter